# Reading other website cookie which is not in our control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies, cross-domain

In our website(asp.net C#) we need to  read a cookie of a particular site(other domain) which is not in our control but the cookie of that site is in our browser(for marketing purposes).how can I read the other domain cookie that exist in current browsers cookies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [You can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible**. 
If the browser allows that its serious security issue.
if you want to access cookie of other site then make your website as subdomain to the website from which you want to access cookie.